# Feeding two ManyToManyFields of one QuerySet into HTML table columns

Tags: django

I have a QuerySet with two ManyToManyFields, let's call them game.players_a and game.players_b. The number of values in one field is almost never the same as in the other field, but typically 1-50. I want to display their values in a template table, something like this:

**game.html**

```
<% for a, b in (game.players_a + game.players_b) %>
<tr>
   <td>a.image</td>
   <td>a.name</td>
   <td>b.image</td>
   <td>b.name</td>
</tr>
<% endfor %>
```

Is there a way to concatenate values from the two ManyToManyFields into a game.players which would look a little like [(Player Object, Player Object), (Player Object, Player Object), (None, Player Object)] or is there a more straightforward way of feeding these values into table columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use the [`izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) function from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

players = izip_longest(game.players_a.all(), game.players_b.all())
return render(request, 'template.html', {'game': game, 'players': players})
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. Amends I've made is I used zip_longest since I failed to mention I'm using Python 3 and I added if blocks in the template to present empty table cells for NoneType values.